# Merge Names From Data For Message Application

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hello guys I'm writing a Message Application with Node.js and Mongoose. I keep datas in mongodb like that:

[image]

I want to list users who messaged before so I need to filter my 'Messages' collection but I can't do what exactly I want. If he sent a message to a person I need to take persons name but, if he take a message from a person I need to take persons name however in first situation person name in reciever, in second situation person name in sender. I made a table for explain more easily. I have left table and I need 3 name like second table.(Need to eliminate one John's name)

[image]

Sorry, if this problem asked before but I don't know how can I search this problem.

I tried this but it take user name who logged in and duplicate some names.

```
Message.find({$or: [{sender: req.user.username}, {reciever: req.user.username}]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use an aggregation pipeline to create two sets and simply union them:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$or: [{sender: req.user.username}, {reciever: req.user.username}]}},
  {$group: {
      _id: 0,
      recievers: {$addToSet: "$reciever"},
      senders: {$addToSet: "$sender"}
  }},
  {$project: {
      _id: req.user.username,
      previousChats: {"$setDifference": 
        [
          {$setUnion: ["$recievers", "$senders"]},
          [req.user.username]
        ]
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aqAXwuP38rx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one, but can be solved with a fairly simple aggregation pipeline.

#### Explanation

On our first stage of the pipeline, we will want to get all the messages sent or received by the user (in our case `David`), for that we will use a `$match` stage:

```js
{
  $match: {
    $or: [
      {sender: 'David'},
      {receiver: 'David'}
    ]
  }
}
```

After we found all the messages from or to `David`, we can start collecting the people he talks to, for that we will use a `$group` stage and use 2 operations that will help us to achieve this:

- $addToSet - This will add all the names to a set. Sets only contain one instance of the same value and ignore any other instance trying to be added to the set of the same value.
- $cond - This will be used to add either the `receiver` or the `sender`, depending which one of them is `David`.

The stage will look like this:

```js
{
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    chats: {$addToSet: {$cond: {
      if: {$eq: ['$sender', 'David']},
      then: '$receiver',
      else: '$sender'
    }}}
  }
}
```

Combining these 2 stages together will give us the expected result, one document looking like this:

```json
{
  "_id": null, // We don't care about this
  "chats": [
    "John",
    "James",
    "Daniel"
  ]
}
```

#### Final Solution

```js
Message.aggregate([{
 $match: {
  $or: [
   {
    sender: req.user.username
   },
   {
    receiver: req.user.username
   }
  ]
 }
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: null,
  chats: {
   $addToSet: {
    $cond: {
     'if': {
      $eq: [
       '$sender',
       req.user.username
      ]
     },
     then: '$receiver',
     'else': '$sender'
    }
   }
  }
 }
}])
```

#### Sources

- [Aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/)
- [$match aggregation stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)
- [$group aggregation stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
- [$addToSet operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)
- [$cond operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)